# Using comparison in assignment in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I need to create a new column in my `data.table` `dt`. This column will contain data from a `data.frame` `df`. My data is as follows:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(letter = LETTERS[1:9], number = 1:9)
dt <- data.table(value = c(0.5, 2.5, 6, 8.5, 4.5, 1.6, 1.3, 7.8, 9.2))
```

Now, I want to create a new column called `col` in `dt` based on the value of `value` that will contain the `letter` from `df` which corresponds to the smallest larger or equal value of `number` than `value`. To give an example, the first row of column `col` should contain `A` since `1` (that is the `number` column from `df` that corresponds to `A`) is the smallest value larger than or equal to 0.5, the `value` in the first row of `dt`. I tried the following code:

```
dt[, col := df[which(value <= df[, 2])[1], 1]]
```

but that puts `A` to all rows. I could this with `data.frame` as follows:

```
setDF(dt)
for(i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
 dt$col[i] <- as.character(df[which(dt$value[i] <= df[, 2])[1], 1])
}
```

which produces the desired output of A, C, F, I, E, B, B, H, and NA. How could I do this with `data.table`?

Comment: @Frank: Wild guess: That's because `df` is created by `data.frame()` which coerces `letters`to `factor`.

Comment: Yes, that is right. I modified the example.

Comment: Okay, alternately, if I change to `dt[i, "col"] <-` it works fine, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a rolling join. However, `number` and `value` will both have to be of the same type first:

```
setDT(df)
df[, number := as.numeric(number)]

dt[, v := df[.SD, on=.(number = value), roll=-Inf, letter]]


   value col  v
1:   0.5   A  A
2:   2.5   C  C
3:   6.0   F  F
4:   8.5   I  I
5:   4.5   E  E
6:   1.6   B  B
7:   1.3   B  B
8:   7.8   H  H
9:   9.2  NA NA
```

To catch problems like this (merging double with integer) more easily, use `verbose`:

```
# when number is still an int...
df[dt, on=.(number = value), roll=-Inf, verbose=TRUE]


Calculated ad hoc index in 0 secs
Coercing double column i.'value' to integer to match type of x.'number'. Please avoid coercion for efficiency.
Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
   letter number
1:      A      0
2:      B      2
3:      F      6
4:      H      8
5:      D      4
6:      A      1
7:      A      1
8:      G      7
9:      I      9
```

You can set verbosity on for the full R session with `options(datatable.verbose = TRUE)`.

Comment: This works, thank you. Is there not a way to specify in `data.table` that only one value at a time should be taken and not the whole column? I believe the behaviour in my original post is caused by the fact that `value` in `dt[, col := df[which(value <= df[, 2])[1], 1]]` is the whole column which gets recycled to only contain 0.5, hence the A's in the entire `col`.

Comment: @Skumin Sorry, I don't think I understand the question. I found your OP approach hard to follow since you were mixing data.frame and data.table syntax and objects.